# How can I increase my AWS s3 upload speed when using boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

Hey there were some similar questions, but none exactly like this and a fair number of them were multiple years old and out of date.

I have written some code on my server that uploads jpeg photos into an s3 bucket using a key via the boto3 method upload_file. Initially this seemed great. It is a super simple solution to uploading files into s3.

The thing is, I have users. My users are sending their jpegs to my server via a phone app. While I concede that I could generate presigned upload URLs and send them to the phone app, that would require a considerable rewrite of our phone app and API.

So I just want the phone app to send the photos to the server. I then want to send the photos from the server to s3. I implemented this but it is way too slow. I cannot ask my users to tolerate those slow uploads.

What can I do to speed this up?

I did some Google searching and found this: https://medium.com/@alejandro.millan.frias/optimizing-transfer-throughput-of-small-files-to-amazon-s3-or-anywhere-really-301dca4472a5

It suggests that the solution is to increase the number of TCP/IP connections. More TCP/IP connections means faster uploads.

Okay, great!

How do I do that? How do I increase the number of TCP/IP connections so I can upload a single jpeg into AWS s3 faster?

Please help.

Comment: Is your application single-threaded? If so, then the limitation is the fact that you are uploading only one image at a time. You could modify your application to send more simultaneously. However, the obvious correct solution is for the phone app to send directly to Amazon S3. This makes it highly scalable and reduces complexity on your back-end server.

Answer (score 46):

Ironically, we've been using `boto3` for years, as well as `awscli`, and we like them both.

But we've often wondered why awscli's `aws s3 cp --recursive`, or `aws s3 sync`, are often so much faster than trying to do a bunch of uploads via `boto3`, even with `concurrent.futures`'s `ThreadPoolExecutor` or `ProcessPoolExecutor` (and don't you even dare sharing the same `s3.Bucket` among your workers: it's warned against in [the docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/resources.html#multithreading-multiprocessing), and for good reasons; nasty crashes will eventually ensue at the most inconvenient time).

Finally, I bit the bullet and looked inside the "customization" code that awscli introduces on top of `boto3`.

Based on that little exploration, here is a way to speed up the upload of many files to S3 by using the concurrency already built in `boto3.s3.transfer`, not just for the possible multiparts of a single, large file, but for a whole bunch of files of various sizes as well. That functionality is, as far as I know, not exposed through the higher level APIs of `boto3` that are described in the `boto3` docs.

The following:

1. Uses `boto3.s3.transfer` to create a `TransferManager`, the very same one that is used by awscli's `aws s3 sync`, for example.
2. Extends the max number of threads to 20.
3. Augments the underlying `urllib3` max pool connections capacity used by `botocore` to match (by default, it uses 10 connections maximum).
4. Gives you an optional callback capability (demoed here with a `tqdm` progress bar, but of course you can have whatever callback you'd like).
5. Is *fast* (over 100MB/s --tested on an ec2 instance).

I put a complete example as a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/pdemarti/a91da8538d630b0cfa48d42b3f41aa45) that includes the generation of 500 random csv files for a total of about 360MB. Here below, we assume you already have a bunch of files in `filelist`, for a total of `totalsize` bytes:

```py
import os
import boto3
import botocore
import boto3.s3.transfer as s3transfer

def fast_upload(session, bucketname, s3dir, filelist, progress_func, workers=20):
    botocore_config = botocore.config.Config(max_pool_connections=workers)
    s3client = session.client('s3', config=botocore_config)
    transfer_config = s3transfer.TransferConfig(
        use_threads=True,
        max_concurrency=workers,
    )
    s3t = s3transfer.create_transfer_manager(s3client, transfer_config)
    for src in filelist:
        dst = os.path.join(s3dir, os.path.basename(src))
        s3t.upload(
            src, bucketname, dst,
            subscribers=[
                s3transfer.ProgressCallbackInvoker(progress_func),
            ],
        )
    s3t.shutdown()  # wait for all the upload tasks to finish
```

Example usage

```py
from tqdm import tqdm

bucketname = '<your-bucket-name>'
s3dir = 'some/path/for/junk'
filelist = [...]
totalsize = sum([os.stat(f).st_size for f in filelist])

with tqdm(desc='upload', ncols=60,
          total=totalsize, unit='B', unit_scale=1) as pbar:
    fast_upload(boto3.Session(), bucketname, s3dir, filelist, pbar.update)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This drastically increased the speed of bucket operations. Wish I could upvote you more than once!

Comment: Would you have to assign the `upload` function to a variable then call `result()`?
such as
`future = s3t.upload(<params>)
future.result()`
That's what worked for me